# Accessing custom object properties as String (NSMutableArray)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Company class where each company has a name, logo, and stock price, all as type String. These are held in an NSMutableArray.

I'm trying to access these properties in a tableview and use them in labels etc.

Here's my Company class:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON



var companyController: CompanyController?

var companies:NSMutableArray? = NSMutableArray()

var applePrice: String?
var googlePrice: String?
var twitterPrice: String?
var teslaPrice: String?
var samsungPrice: String?

var stockPrices = [String]()

let stockUrl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20symbol%2C%20Ask%2C%20YearHigh%2C%20YearLow%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22TWTR%22%2C%22TSLA%22%2C%20%22SSNLF%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"



class Company: NSObject {

var companyName: String?
var companyLogo: String?
var stockPrice: String?
init(companyName:String, companyLogo:String, stockPrice:String) {
    self.companyName = companyName
    self.companyLogo = companyLogo
    self.stockPrice = stockPrice

    companies?.add(apple)
    companies?.add(google)
    companies?.add(twitter)
    companies?.add(tesla)
    companies?.add(samsung)
}
}




func stockFetcher() {

Alamofire.request(stockUrl).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
    if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
        let json = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
        if let appleStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][0]["Ask"].string {
            print(appleStockPrice)
            applePrice = appleStockPrice
        }
        if let googleStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][1]["Ask"].string {
            print(googlePrice)
            googlePrice = googleStockPrice
        }
        if let twitterStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][2]["Ask"].string {
            print(twitterStockPrice)
            twitterPrice = twitterStockPrice
        }
        if let teslaStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][3]["Ask"].string {
            print(teslaStockPrice)
            teslaPrice = teslaStockPrice
        }
        if let samsungStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][4]["Ask"].string {
            print(samsungStockPrice)
            samsungPrice = samsungStockPrice
        }
        let stockPriceArray = [applePrice, googlePrice, twitterPrice, teslaPrice, samsungPrice]
        stockPrices = stockPriceArray as! [String]
        companyController?.tableView.reloadData()
        print(json)
    }
}
}


let apple = Company(companyName: "Apple", companyLogo: "AppleLogo", stockPrice: applePrice!)
let google = Company(companyName: "Google", companyLogo: "GoogleLogo", stockPrice: googlePrice!)
let twitter = Company(companyName: "Twitter", companyLogo: "TwitterLogo", stockPrice: twitterPrice!)
let tesla = Company(companyName: "Tesla", companyLogo: "TeslaLogo", stockPrice: teslaPrice!)
let samsung = Company(companyName: "Samsung", companyLogo: "SamsungLogo", stockPrice: samsungPrice!)
```

In my CompanyController, I initialize

```
var company = [Company]()
```

and now would like to use the company info in the cells, so for example in cellForRowAt indexPath I want to assign the company names to the text labels.

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CompanyCell

    //Text label
    cell.textLabel?.text = <what goes here?>[indexPath.row]
```

How can I access the company properties inside the NSMutableArray to get the name, etc? I'm hoping to be able to do something like

```
company.companies.companyName[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'll need "company.CompanyProperty" you can create a array and put all companies. 
In the function you can get easily all the proprieties:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = [indexPath.row].companyName
cell.textLabel?.text2 = [indexPath.row].companyLogo
cell.textLabel?.text3 = [indexPath.row].stockPrice
```

Comment: I think that's probably what I'll have to do, I'm just wondering if there's a way to grab the properties directly from my NSMutableArray, without having to give each property a separate array to draw from.